# Fixed Table Header Scrolling

Tags: html, css

With some tips found on this web site I was able to put together a fixed table header scrolling page. It works as expected until I add the  container to each row (to each  tag). Having the container is a must have for my app to use certain pre-existing functionality that is based on the  container.

Here's my CSS:

```
<style>
table.tableFixedHdr {
    border:1px solid
}
tr td{
    border:none
}
tbody.tbScroll {
    display:block;
    max-height:200px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
thead.thFixed, tbody tr.trFixed {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
thead {
    width:100%; 
}
table.tableFixedHdr {
    width:60%;
}
</style>
```

And here's a simplified version of the table:

```
<table class="tableFixedHdr">
    <thead class="thFixed">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Segment</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody class="tbScroll">
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>  
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>
    <tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It works fine until I add the  container, as follows:

```
<tbody><tr class="trFixed"><td>01/01/2021</td><td>3859303</td><td>ALA</td><td>KEY</td><td>Very Old Customer</td><td>250</td></tr></tbody>
```

Once I add the  container the header row is no longer fixed.

Does anyone have an idea of how to get around this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tried you this?

```
<thead>
<tr class="thFixed">
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Segment</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Count</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

Then:

```
thead tr.thFixed, tbody tr.trFixed {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I replace thead.thFixed, tbody tr.trFixed {...}  with thead tr.thFixed, tbody tr.trFixed {...}? if so it doesn't do it with the <tbody> row container.

Comment: @genek54 But why? Want you all `rows` to be `fixed`?

Comment: I want my header row to be locked/fixed when scrolling up and down. It's working until I add the TBODY  container around each TR element.

Comment: @genek54 So why do you set `tbody tr.trFixed` to `table-layout: fixed;`  if you want only your header to be fixed?

Comment: Hi Arman, the styles I have shared do work as expected, with the header row staying in place when i scroll the rows up and  down. That is until i add the tbody tags. So i'm trying to see if anyone has an idea why this messes things up and can suggest how to correct that. Thank you.